# numbers runner : gambling in the US in the 1920/1930's

Tags: traduction, anglais

This is related to numbers, a game in the 1920 and 1930's in the US.

A gambler places a bet with a bookie at a tavern, bar, barber shop, social club, or any other semi-private place that acts as an illegal betting parlor. A numbers runner carries the money and betting slips between the betting parlors and the headquarters, called a numbers bank or policy bank.

I wonder if there is any equivalent in French illegal gambling of the same period (or today).

Answer (score 3):

A pejorative way to say *a gambling place* would be **un tripot** so I guess **un tripot clandestin** would fit well for *an illegal gambling place*

now for *illegal gambling* (so, the action, not place) 
**paris clandestins** would be ok for bets 
**jeux d'argent clandestins** would be ok for gambling in general

maybe someone will find something more appropriate though